# Output looped array data to separate columns in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, multiple-columns

I have three loops which process array data and print to the same log file. I would like to sort the output of each loop into columns which are separated by tabs using bash code:

```
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
```

Notice: 1 stands for the content of loop 1, 2 stands for the content of loop 2 and 3 stands for the content of loop 3.

```
declare -a Array1
declare -a Array2
declare -a Array3

for (( i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++))
do
echo "${Array1[$i]}"
done | tee -a log.txt


for (( i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++))
do
echo "(( ${Array1[$i]}-${Array2[$i]} ))" | bc
done | tee -a log.txt


for (( i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++))
do
echo "${Array3[$i]}"
done | tee -a log.txt
```

I tried some stuff with the column command, but it doesn't work out as outlined above.

Comment: Use a different file for each loop, and then join them with paste: `patse log[1-9].txt`

Comment: @Joe Lo: Are you planning to use a single loop to print all columns? or just separate loop for each column?

Comment: @Indian: A single loop would also be possible.

Comment: @user000001: I would prefer a cleaner solution though :)) Will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option may be to use a single loop.

An alternative is to take the output format that you've got already and convert it into columns.  This is one way of doing it:

```
# Read the concatenated results into an array, $results
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a results < log.txt

# Print the concatenated results in columns
for (( i=0 ; i<9; i++ )) ; do
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "${results[i]}" "${results[i+9]}" "${results[i+18]}"
done
```

If you don't need the `log.txt` file, you could just put the results into an array as you calculate them (using as many loops as you like) and print them afterwards.